# Returning an variable of class' type by value from the method

Tags: c++, copy, return-value, copy-constructor

Good day,gentlemens!
Lets consider the code:

```
class Test
{
    int a;
public:
Test(){}
Test( Test& t){cout<<"hello\n";} //copy constructor
Test foo() { return Test();}




};

int main()
{
    Test t;


}
```

The issue is that given code isn't compiled.If we delete the copy constructor everything goes well. What is the problem? Adding the *const* --`Test(const Test& t)` solves the problem, but I can't understand why. Could anybody explain it? Thanks!

Comment: Ladies not allowed? :(

Comment: Clean up your sample code, add a call too foo, to make it complete, and read and understand compiler errors and warnings (which you should not ignore, unless you know the reason, impacts and the proper way to blend the warning out)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, it's always allowed for the smart ones :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Test( Test& t){cout<<"hello\n";}
```

Yes, this *is* a copy constructor.

However, we usually write it like this:

```
Test(const Test& t){cout<<"hello\n";}
```

That's because it's *far* more useful this way; it's the only way we can ever copy-construct a `Test` from a "temporary" (e.g. your expression `Test()`), because only references-to-`const` (and rvalue references) may bind to temporaries.

It's the same as the following problem:

```
      int& r1 = 3;    // :(
const int& r2 = 3;    // :D
```

or:

```
      int& r1 = f();  // :(
const int& r2 = f();  // :D
```